# AutoHotKey: "{Enter" Hotstring

Tags: tabs, autohotkey, braces

As I've started using AutoHotKey daily, I thought it'd be a good idea to implement it in my coding.

I'd like it to create a structure like this:

```
{
    (Tab)
}
```

when `{` followed by an `Enter` are entered.

So far, I've got:

```
:*{Enter::
    SendInput, {{}
    SendInput, {Enter}
    SendInput, {Enter}
    SendInput, {}}
    SendInput, {Up}
    SendInput, {Tab}
return
```

but I keep getting errors and strange anomalies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things that must be included in order to get your code to work:
1. a backtick must be used for a curly bracket to be in hotstring
2. the option 'o' must be used to prevent a return from being sent after a curly bracket within your send command.

Try the following:

```
:o:`{::{{}`n`n{}}{up}{tab}
```

[Hotstring options](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)

Note: You may need to modify ending characters for this to fire only on Enter.  This will affect hotstrings globally.

```
#Hotstring EndChars `n
```

Comment: Ooo, that's very promising! However, I notice that the command executes on more key presses than the, requested, sequential `Enter`. Could that be implemented?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a way to do this.  However, it does affect hotstrings globally, so I would suggest putting it in a script separate from other hotstrings.  There may be another way by using KeyWait that would be worth exploring if this is not satisfactory.

Comment: Well, I just implemented your suggested method and then tested all of my scripts. They all seem to be working flawlessly. I tip my hat to you, good sir. Thank you, very much. If I have any issues I'll report back to you. Could you give me any examples of potential issues, though?

Comment: #Hotstring does not affect hotstrings that have an * in their options.  For others, I would think that if you wanted your hotstrings to fire when pressing any other keys such as tab, space, ;, etc. they may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Send, {{}{Enter}{tab}{Enter}{}}{up}{End}
```

This works for me, but your hotkey "*{Enter" was not accepted by my AutoHotKey_L, so I used an other temporary hotkey "^q".

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the commands, it's with the hotstring. I need to get `{Enter` to work, somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This hotstring worked for me.

```
:*:`{`n::
```

That should catch it without need for settning the EndChars.